# Matplotlib 1.3.1 with python 3.4 creates corrupt eps files

Tags: python, matplotlib, postscript, eps

After upgrading ubuntu and python, matplotlib started creating corrupt files. I've tried installing it on another computer and it does the same. A simple code from examples:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10), range(10))
plt.title("Simple Plot")
plt.savefig('test.eps')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

test.png seems to be fine, while test.eps is corrupted (doesn't open in document viewer). There is no error message so I have no idea what could it be.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't document viewer?

Comment: Well I've tried importing them to latex document and while they get converted to pdf and imported, they are corrupted there as well. Only 1 plot per figure is shown with no labels, ticks, grid, etc. This is with the same code that worked for me a month ago before upgrading.

Comment: Can you put the eps file someplace?  I just ran this with master + 3.4 and gwenview opens it just fine.

Comment: @tcaswell
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZ3t_dhG-fPYnp6MzkxeVJIOEE/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZ3t_dhG-fPUERvd0UtU1lUUTg/edit?usp=sharing
here are .png and .eps files produced with the quote from the question
edit: apparently it's fine when viewed online on google drive. Weird. But on I can't open the files on neither of my computers (running ubuntu and xubuntu 14.04), or if they are used in tex docuemnts they are corrupted (no labels, no ticks, etc., just the line). I can view old .eps files and include them in tex documents without problem though.

Comment: What version of python were you using before?  I would also point out that we don't currently test on 3.4, just 3.2 and 3.3...Probably should do something about that...

Comment: I think it was 1.3.1 on python 3.2. But I'm not exactly sure. For some reason in the old .eps files it says matplotlib 1.2.1 but I doubt that's correct as I've installed it only 3 months ago from ubuntu repositories.

Comment: no, that sounds right.  The packaging lags significantly  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=matplotlib&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: @tcaswell
Ah I see. Well for now I'm fine with just exporting to .pdf which seems to work for me as well. May I ask if you can open the .eps file I provided normally after downloading it?

Comment: yes, it opens fine in gwen view for me (from ubuntu 14.04)